# Django: text fixture fails to load

Tags: django, testing, fixtures

Did a dumpdata of my project, then in my new test I added it to fixtures.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestGoal(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data.json']
    
    def test_goal(self):
        """
        Tests that 1 + 1 always equals 2.
        """
        self.failUnlessEqual(1 + 1, 2)
```

When running the test I get:

> Problem installing fixture
> 'XXX/fixtures/test_data.json':
>
> DoesNotExist: XXX matching query does
> not exist.

But manually doing loaddata <strike>works fine</strike> does not when the db is empty.
I do a dropdb, createdb a simple syncdb the try loaddata and it fails, same error.

Any clue?

Python version 2.6.5, Django 1.1.1

Comment: is test_data.json available under the fixtures/ directory? How does test_data.json looks like?

Comment: is available there and looks like data from manage.py dumpdata command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you have some foreign key troubles.  If you have a model that contains a foreign key referring to another model but the other model doesn't exist, you'll get this error.

This can happen for a couple of reasons: if you are pointing to a model in another app that you didn't include in the test_data.json dump, you'll have trouble.

Also, if foreign keys change, this can break serialization -- this is especially problematic with automatically created fields like [permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id1) or [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1).  Django 1.2 supports [natural keys](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys), which are a way to serialize using the "natural" representation of a model as a foreign key rather than an ID which might change.